# Saving Word 2010 Document to PDF with Index

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010, adobe-acrobat

I need to save a Word 2010 document to PDF to send to the printer. The problem is that the PDF file is 16 pages shorter (408 vs 424) than the Word document, so the references in the Index no longer match the page numbers correctly. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Look for a page scaling option in the print dialog(s) and make sure it's not scaling on its way to PDF.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the PDF?  Since you tagged this "Adobe-Acrobat", are you actually using it for something in this workflow?  What page size is set for the document in Word? What page size is being produced in the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual, by default the only thing I can think of is you have a font issue. Or you have some weird margin. Try setting adobe preferences to default in the acrobat interface in MSWord and see if that helps.

The other issue I have seen with acrobat pro is that sometimes on conversion it leaves out some of the white space, so if I have pages with a lot of space at the bottom, it sometimes loses some of it and moves the text up. To fix this you need to retain the page layout.

What I do is check what printer my document is set for, and choose the adobe one. Documents can have varied layouts depending what printer they think they're laid out for.